# How to prevent my application to get cached value of TimeZone.getDefault()?

Tags: android, calendar, timezone

I am using `TimeZone.getDefault()` to set the timezone of `Calendar` class:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
Log.i("TEST", cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

**However**, when users change the timezone of their device from Setting, my application represents the time using the former timezone until they force stop (from App info settings) the application and restart it.

How could I prevent the caching of `getDefault()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not pretty, but you could potentially call `setDefault(null)` to explicitly wipe the cached value. As per [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)), this will only affect the current process (that is, your app).

Having nulled out the cached value, the next time you call `getDefault()`, the value is reconstructed freshly:

```
/**
 * Returns the user's preferred time zone. This may have been overridden for
 * this process with {@link #setDefault}.
 *
 * <p>Since the user's time zone changes dynamically, avoid caching this
 * value. Instead, use this method to look it up for each use.
 */
public static synchronized TimeZone getDefault() {
    if (defaultTimeZone == null) {
        TimezoneGetter tzGetter = TimezoneGetter.getInstance();
        String zoneName = (tzGetter != null) ? tzGetter.getId() : null;
        if (zoneName != null) {
            zoneName = zoneName.trim();
        }
        if (zoneName == null || zoneName.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                // On the host, we can find the configured timezone here.
                zoneName = IoUtils.readFileAsString("/etc/timezone");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // "vogar --mode device" can end up here.
                // TODO: give libcore access to Android system properties and read "persist.sys.timezone".
                zoneName = "GMT";
            }
        }
        defaultTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneName);
    }
    return (TimeZone) defaultTimeZone.clone();
}
```

You should probably combine this with a broadcast listener for [`ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED) and only null out the default value if you receive such a broadcast.

---

Edit: come to think of it, a neater solution would be to extract the newly set time zone from the broadcast. From the broadcast documentation:

> time-zone - The java.util.TimeZone.getID() value identifying the new time zone.

You can then simply use this identifier to update the cached default:

```
String tzId = ...
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tzId));
```

Any subsequent calls to `getDefault()` will then return the correct/updated time zone.